# Move to div after content is shown dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and a result `div` that is hidden when the page is loaded. After the user submit the form the result is shown below the form. The height might vary, so I want to move to the top of that `div` to display the full content at first sight.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var search = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#loading").css('display', 'block');
  var userValue = $("#username").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "random.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { username: userValue },
    success: function (response) {
      var scrollTo = $('#resultCard'), //the div I want to move to
        container = $('html,body');
      $("#loading").hide();
      scrollTo.show().animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
      var title = response["title"];
      var desc = response["desc"];
      var poster = response["poster"];
      if(title === null) {
        $("#resultTitle").text("Invalid User");
        $("#resultDesc").hide();
        $("#resultButtons").hide();
        $(".ptw-image").css("cssText", "background-color: red !important;");
      } else {
        $("#resultTitle").text(title);
        $("#resultDesc").html(desc).show();
        $("#resultButtons").show();
        $(".ptw-image").css('background', "url(" + poster + ") center / cover");
        container.animate({
          scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And here the `div`:

```
<div style="display:none;margin-top:5px;" id="resultCard" class="ptw-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white ptw-image">
        <h2 id="resultTitle" class="mdl-card__title-text ptw-text-shadow"> </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="resultDesc" class="mdl-card__supporting-text"> </div>
    <div id="resultButtons" class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a id="resultInfo" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">More Info</a>
        <a id="rollAgain" style="float:right;" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Another one</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to scroll to a particular element in this case `#resultCard` is by doing this:

```
document.getElementById('resultCard').scrollIntoView();
```

If you wish to animate the scrolling action you can do that easily with jQuery like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#resultCard").offset().top
});
```

Comment: How are you implementing the second one? Can you post some code in an edit. Are there any errors in your console? It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/svph1cfo/

Answer (score 0):

### How to Solve

Simply we are submitting and reading that scroll position index . Also setting scroll position index via Javascript in onload event.

#### Add following to get/post method signature

```
@RequestParam(value = "windowScrollOffset", required = false) Integer windowScrollOffset,
```

#### Add following to get/post method

```
model.addAttribute("windowScrollOffset", windowScrollOffset);
```

#### Add following to form

```
<input type="hidden" id="windowScrollOffset" name="windowScrollOffset" />
```

#### Run following js onload

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
window.onscroll = function(){ document.getElementById('windowScrollOffset').value = (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset);};
window.scroll(0, parseInt('${windowScrollOffset}'));   

} );
```

Reference article:

http://codexamples.blogspot.com/2016/07/keep-last-scroll-position-in-web.html